# C# HttpClient.SendAsync await throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dotnet-httpclient

First of all, I'm attempting to build a plugin for a product - so the environment is not mine and I don't have a ton of visibility into what's going on. As far as I can tell, the system is running .NET Framework 4.6.2, and I've tried to ensure all my dependencies match what's on the system.

The issue I'm seeing is that when I issue a `await PostAsync(...)` request, I get a `NullReferenceException`. This is 100% reproducible. However, if I make the exact same request using `PostAsync(...).Result`, everything works properly.

This is made stranger given that I can use the `await` keyword on the parsing of the response, and it still works correctly.

I want to do it the 'right' way, using the `await` keyword, but it just doesn't work. From everything I've been reading, it's likely a dependency issue, but I don't know where to look to find it. I've spent 3 days on this already, when I *finally* discovered that using `.Result` 'fixes' my issue.

Relevant code:

```
private async Task<T> aFunction<T>(string path, Dictionary<string, string> data) {
  var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
  var response = client.PostAsync(path, content).Result; // This works
  // var response = await client.PostAsync(path, content); // This does not
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result);
  return parsed;
}
```

Stack Trace of the NRE:

```
Stack trace:
at System.Web.ThreadContext.AssociateWithCurrentThread(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallbackPossiblyUnderLock(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallback(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback(ContextCallback callback, Object state, Task& currentTask)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.<>c.<ThrowAsyncIfNecessary>b__18_0(Object s)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

Comment: For me it seems like this is not the average NPE, but more of a configuration issue as @Martin Zikmunds answer suggests. I won't close the question as duplicate right now.

Comment: I voted to re-open the issue as the actual problem was that I was running a control on an ASPX page. The control made an async call to a library, but the page was not configured as async (no `<% Page async="true"%>`). I can provide an actual answer to the question if it is re-opened.

Comment: Vote for reopen, the duplicate is absolutely unrelated to the actual problem, please see the OPs comment on my answer. The whole issue revolves around thread synchronization rather than NullReference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ASPX page that was hosting the plugin is not async, I could not use async methods inside my handler. I ended up having to ensure that I use synchronous calls instead of the async ones.

To prove this, after adding the line (recommended by Martin)

```
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
```

and using the await calls, my plugin started to hang after making the request.

This SO page: [Async Deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879340/async-deadlock), implied to me that the page on which my plugin was sitting was not properly setup for async functionality. I tried adding the RegisterAsyncTask, and in the logs I see a new message:

InvalidOperationException: This operation requires the page to be asynchronous (the Async attribute must be set to true).

Answer (score 4):

I would try using some of the suggestions [listed here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/).

Especially try adding the following `appSetting` in `web.config`:

```
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
```

And the following `httpRuntime` element in `system.web`:

```
<system.Web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.Web>
```

Comment: That was a quick turnaround. I'll see if I can get that info from the hosts. I likely won't get an update until tomorrow.

Comment: That could be the cause. It seems that several people have had similar issues, because the SynchronizationContext is not properly set in older versions unless the setting is properly set.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance Martin. Using your `appSetting` change, I was able to narrow down the real issue - namely that the ASPX page on which my plugin was running was not configured for async processing.